# How to get hold of the (un)marshalled message for logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, xstream

I have a Spring MVC REST service that uses XStream to convert the messages to and from XML.

Is there any way I can print the xml (ie the body) from the request and response to a normal log4j logger?

Inside the controller won't work cause by then XStream has alread unmarshalled the request and not yet marshalled the response.

A filter in the servlet isn't very nice either as it will consume the body by reading it.

And thats where I run out if ideas. So, SO? Any takers? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) to log your request and response content coming to your specific rest uri's - [More details here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

Comment: I'll try some more tomorrow but isn't the request/response just streams internally? If so, I can't read them with out also destroying them.

Comment: You are right @Andreas, Interceptor will not work. I see one technique here - http://www.wetfeetblog.com/servlet-filer-to-log-request-and-response-details-and-payload/431, which consumes the stream, but then replaces the HttpRequest and HttpResponse with an adapted version, with the request and the response internally buffered up.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen such solutions. Spring even has this internally in it's AbstractRequestLoggingFilter although I think it's a bad and buggy implementation.

Comment: I'm awarding for this solution. My only real idea was to do as wetfeetblog does but I hadn't found that link and I fear I won't get an better solution.